# sympyのplotのgcaのAttributeErrorを教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy

細長く表示します。
(参考)大学入試問題で現れる世界遺産
https://qiita.com/kazukiii/items/bbb55f873730b6e31f2b

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
var('x')
F  = x**4 - x**2 + 6
G = cos(2 * pi * x) / 2 + 7 / 2
H = 12 / (abs(x) + 1)
p1 = plot(F, (x, -1, 1), show=False)
p2 = plot(G, (x, -2, 2), show=False)
p4 = plot(H, (x, -8,-1), show=False)
p3 = plot(H, (x,  1 ,8), show=False)
p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.extend(p4)
# p1.gca().set_aspect('equal')
p1.show()
#   File "C:/Users/xxx/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_30.py", line 85, in <module>
#     p1.gca().set_aspect('equal')
# AttributeError: 'Plot' object has no attribute 'gca'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sympy`の`plot`は、`gca`で`axes`を取得できないのでエラーになっています。
また、`sympy`の`plot`は、`set_aspect`でアスペクトを設定できないようです。

参考資料 [「sympy.plottingでaspect_ratioが変えられない？」について調べてみた](https://funmatu.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/sympy-plotting%E3%81%A7aspect_ratio%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%89%E3%81%88%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%EF%BC%9F/)

`sympy`の`plot`は、もともと簡易的なものなので、参考にあるように`figure.figsize`を適当に決めて合わせるぐらいしかないと思います。

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

var('x')
F  = x**4 - x**2 + 6
G = cos(2 * pi * x) / 2 + 7 / 2
H = 12 / (abs(x) + 1)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 6)
p1 = plot(F, (x, -1, 1), show=False)
p2 = plot(G, (x, -2, 2), show=False)
p4 = plot(H, (x, -8,-1), show=False)
p3 = plot(H, (x,  1 ,8), show=False)
p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.extend(p4)
p1.show()
```

カスタマイズしたい場合は、(参考)「大学入試問題で現れる世界遺産」のように最初からmatplotlibで記述する方がいいと思われます。